# Remove controller in some environment in grails

Tags: grails, controller

I made some controller but he only have purpose in test environment and I am wondering is there some elegant way to plug in or plug off him depend of environment? ...

Concretely I must delete some database tables in test environment and has to be from API because it is for functional tests so I must make controller/service for that. Of Course I don't want to have this controller in production environment for security reasons :D

Thanks for any suggestion!

Ivan

Answer (score 2):

Not sure will it be elegant enough, but you can just add url mapping redirecting to 404 page for that controller on environments different than TEST:

conf/UrlMappings.groovy

```
static mappings = {

    // ...

    if (Environment.current != Environment.TEST) {
        '/testcontrollername'(view: '/404page')
    }
}
```

Another thing which can be done is to delete the controller class from WAR directory before archive build. This will work only if you deploy with WAR, of course.

Comment: Conversely, how about having the mapping to controller in TEST env only??

Comment: This is good idea but it is not working. I cannot set url-mapping inside if clause :/

Comment: Why it so? I did that many times. As far as I'm aware there is no problem with if statements at UrlMappings.groovy.

Comment: I don't understand...it just don't recognize mapping then and nothing happens and when I put it outside if it works ... I've put if clause in controller itself and it works there...it is not the most elegant solution but I can live with that :)

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem right now. Here is something among Grails samples https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website/blob/master/grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy and there is 'if' statement at UrlMappings. It has to be working, no doubts on that. Could you please post your UrlMappings.groovy and the steps you are trying to test it?